# MongoDB: Find a value in an array which is not an _id in another collection

Tags: mongodb

In a database I'm working with, there is a collection of `Users`, and a collection of `Groups`. The `Groups` model contains an array, `user_ids`, which correspond to `_id` values of individual users. Each group has a different set of users.

My problem is, I've accidentally deleted a record from the `Users` collection, and it turns out that this may cause a crash if some code references a group, which in turn references that user.

So what I need to do is, figure out how to query mongo in such a way that it tells me any `user_id` which does *not* correspond to the `_id` of an item in the `Users` collection.

Can anyone suggest code that can do this, or point me in the right direction toward the operations I should be using? I am pretty new to Mongo so I unfortunately haven't yet learned much of the relevant termiology. Thanks so much for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 1):

Get the list of ids from the users collection, then use $nin to find the groups that reference nonexistent users. Unless you have millions of users this should work acceptably well and be quick to code.

Comment: Thanks, makes great sense. How woud you go about getting that list of ids?

Comment: Not sure I follow you there. How to do that? Is there something I can type at a Robo3T command line that would produce that array of _ids?

Comment: I would personally use ruby, I would suggest python as a more common language, you could do this via js in mongo shell also. GUI tool probably not the best.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the opposite way, put the groupId on the user document then you can query all users with groupId of anything and when you delete a user his groupId field also gets deleted which is what you want.